# Why does a virtual box VM take up more space after I import it?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I downloaded a VM from here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines

The zip file was about ~20GB, and the .ova file inside was also ~20GB.
But after I imported it into virtual box on my Mac, the space occupied by the VM's folder is 45GB!

I thought the zip file was the compressed file, and the .ova file is just a regular decompressed file.... Is my VM taking up more space than it should ? Is this expected ? Anyway to reduce the space it is taking up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OVA file is a [tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) archive and is not compressed. It contains the disk image(s) in VMDK format (other formats are also possible though).

The VMDK images inside the OVA are compressed.

If you import the OVA in Virtualbox, the disk images will be decompressed and thus be bigger than the compressed ones (even if your disks are 'dynamic' ones).

For details, see [inside-the-ovf-package](https://blogs.vmware.com/vapp/2009/08/inside-the-ovf-package.html), in particular section `Disk Formats and Compression`.